# Display maps infoWindow correctly in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps, infowindow

How can I cycle through the values of an associative array? Now I can only take one association at a time! Here I'm passing to the json_encode all the values from a MySQL table taking only the lat & long as array of an array and the other Strings. Thank you

```
function myMap() {

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.849716, 10.052282),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
      styles: []
  };

  var i = 0;
  var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
  var markers = <?= json_encode($this->getCoordinatesMaps[0]); ?>; //Passing the PHP values to JS


  var marker, i;
  //Add marker to map
  for(var i in markers) {
      var marker = markers[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.long),
          map: map,
          title: 'Niente',
          clickable: true
      });


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(<?= json_encode($this->getCoordinatesMaps[0]->comune); ?> + ' - ' + <?= json_encode($this->getCoordinatesMaps[0]->mansione_tecnica); ?>);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The setContent method requires a string. You are passing multiple arguments

`infowindow.setContent(markers[i].lat, markers[i].long);`

The correct way should be:
`infowindow.setContent('My content here');`

Comment: Well it's not a race, or at least it should not be. But I have to say that it's fun and challenging that you have to debug and write the solution as fast as possible

Comment: Welp, didn't mean that'd be a competition, but `But I have to say that it's fun and challenging that you have to debug and write the solution as fast as possible` could be fun :)

Comment: Yes. I'm figured out how to place multiple markers with the "for" cycle but I'm not succeeding in put their contents in the infoWindow @Rick_Jellema

Comment: @GiuseppeAlbrizio Edit and elaborate your question. Are you trying to place multiple markers on the map, with each their own content in the infoWindow ?

Comment: I think it should be simple. Do you pass any content you'd like to display in the infowindow from PHP to Json?

Comment: Yes exactly. I've used this to pass lat and long to the google maps LatLng function: json_encode($this->getCoordinatesMaps);

Comment: @GiuseppeAlbrizio Those are the coordinates of where your 'company/infowindow' should be placed. what I mean is do pass anthing to the yourmapfile.js that contains html code with more info for the infowindow bubble?

Comment: I use a static map right now for my website. With this content: 
`let html = "<div id='mapwindow'>" +
                    "<h3>" + title + "</h3>" +
                    "<p>" + address + "</p>" +
                    "<p>" + desc + "<br>" +
                    "<a target='_blank' href='" + url + "'>Weergeven in Google maps</a>" +
                    "</p>" +
                    "</div>";
                iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: html,
                    maxWidth: 350
                });`

Comment: No for now I'm just trying to pass those infos (lat and long) to the infoWindow. I'm using the geocode script to convert the name of each address in lat and long and I'd like to understand how to pass those infos to the infoWindow to add something else later

Comment: Alright, Try this [Google Map API Reverse GeoCoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) documentation. Since you pass long lat coordinates. You need to geolocate the adresses. I think this documentation explains alot. I can't do an example now, since I'm short on time.

Comment: @Rick_Jellema In the end I figured out how to include everything in the map also for the infoWindow. Would be cool share with you the solution! :)

Comment: @GiuseppeAlbrizio Goodjob. Totally fergot about this question. Sorry.. But sure post your solution as an answer!

Comment: Done! :) Thank you for your help anyway!! @Rick_Jellema

Answer (score 1):

Here it is the solution to my previous question. Maybe can help someone trying to do the same thing. Then I also add a GET form to easily change the date in which you would see worker around the globe. :)

```
function myMap() {

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.849716, 10.052282),
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        styles: []
    };

    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    var markersArray = '<?= json_encode($this->getCoordinatesMaps); ?>';//Passing the PHP values to JS
    markers = JSON.parse(markersArray); //Reading array values
    // console.log(markers[1].comune);

    var marker, i; //Defining this function for infoWindow

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    // console.log(markers[i].latlng.lat + ' is a ' + markers[i].latlng.long + '.');
    var marker = markers[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].latlng.lat, markers[i].latlng.long),
        map: map,
        title: markers[i].surname + ' ' + markers[i].name,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        clickable: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
              infowindow.setContent("<div><img width='120' height='30' src='/images/logo.png'</div><hr />" + '<strong>Address: </strong> ' + markers[i].address + ' <strong>Event Name: </strong> ' + markers[i].event_name  + ' <strong>Worker: </strong> ' + markers[i].name+ ' ' + markers[i].surname + ' <strong>Work: </strong> ' + markers[i].technical_work + ' <strong>Client: </strong>' + markers[i].client_name);
              infowindow.setOptions({maxWidth: 300});
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
      })(marker, i));
    }
```

}